# How to use webp picture format in Unity3D project?

Tags: android, c++, unity-game-engine, webp

I already integrated the webp source code to a C++ game engine that i'm using, it's working fine and the android apk is mucher smaller than before.

Now for my other Unity3d project, is possible to use webp, too(reducing the package size is now my major concern)? if yes, how can i do it, do i need to implement some kind of importer plugin??

it would be really helpful if someone can point me the way, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you will have to use some plugins for webp images. Unity till now does not have support for this format. [This](https://github.com/octo-code/webp-unity3d) git project though is a good starting point.

For reducing the size of the apk, you could definitely use other formats supported by unity3d. You could try the ASTC compression which is available for android unity3d. I hope that you are aware of the sprite packer in unity3d also which could pack the sprites if you are in 2d mode. Also you could see the Editor log after the build to see which part of your apk (textures, plugins, scrips) is consuming the size. Hope this helps.